# BLE scan with ThinkPad X1 on Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hci

Ubuntu 21.04, ThinkPad X1.

I am failing to scan BLE:

```
$ hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

Running `sudo btmon` while running the above command yields:

```
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22                                         {0x0002} 13.597363
@ RAW Close: hcitool                                                                  {0x0002} 13.597386
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22                                  {0x0002} [hci0] 13.597399
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                         #396 [hci0] 13.597462
        Type: Active (0x01)
        Interval: 10.000 msec (0x0010)
        Window: 10.000 msec (0x0010)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Accept all advertisement (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                        #397 [hci0] 13.712003
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Command Disallowed (0x0c)
@ RAW Close: hcitool
```

I'm a bit surprised by the Interval and Window being the same. If scanning 100 % of the time, how can for example my bluetooth mouse work at the same time?

Anyway, this scans successfully (it actually stopped working for a while, but `power off` / `power on` solved it. `MX Anywhere 2S` is my bluetooth mouse):

```
$ bluetoothctl
[MX Anywhere 2S]# menu scan
[MX Anywhere 2S]# clear
[MX Anywhere 2S]# transport le
[MX Anywhere 2S]# back
[MX Anywhere 2S]# scan on
```

All the beacons I'm looking for are there in the output of `btmon`.

Yet on the other hand, `hcitool lescan` still says "Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error". How do I solve that?

This might be relevant:

```
$ ps aux|grep blue
gauthier  260395  0.0  0.0  45708  6900 ?        Ss   10:45   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
root      261745  0.2  0.0  11276  5700 ?        Ss   10:53   0:01 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
gauthier  262297  0.0  0.0  20636  2896 pts/2    S+   11:01   0:00 grep --color=auto blue

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 04:56:E5:E7:1A:34  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:37504193 acl:540593 sco:0 events:539220 errors:0
    TX bytes:815046 acl:258 sco:0 commands:3643 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'taket'
    Class: 0x3c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Revision: 0x2279
    LMP Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Subversion: 0x2279
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Comment: It is best not to use the `hci*` tools as they have been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) . The current equivalent of `hci*` tools is `btmgmt`. `bluetoothctl` can be used for most user activities. To see all the beacon data with `bluetoothctl`, when you are in `menu scan` you need to set `duplicate-data on`.

Comment: ukBaz: thanks, I was aware of `bluetoothctl`, but not of `btmgmt`.

Comment: Thanks @ukBaz! The `duplicate-data on` made the difference in my case (connecting a [Logitech LIFT](https://www.logitech.com/nl-nl/products/mice/lift-vertical-ergonomic-mouse.html) to my Dell 5530 (Intel Wireless-AC 9260). Took me only an hour to figure this out..